# faster way to implement a code mySQL subqueries

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

I am trying to find the total number of customers in table_Y who hold distinct number of titles and have them grouped by their marital_status which is in table_X. I cannot join them because I do not have an unique key to join them. I am writing the following mySQL script which takes forever. Is there a better way to write this? Thanks:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id), marital_status FROM table_X
    WHERE customer_id IN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)
    FROM
    (
    SELECT customer_id,COUNT(DISTINCT title) 
    FROM table_Y
    GROUP BY customer_id 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT title)=1
    ORDER BY customer_id) as t1)
    GROUP BY marital_status;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Even if your query seems to work, I'm almost certain it won't return you the desired results, mainly because of `WHERE customer_id IN ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) ....` `customer_id` should have nothing to do with business related values.
2. It seems that you can do a join, since both your tables contain the `customer_id` column, which presumably represents the same thing, thus you could do:

   SELECT customer_id,COUNT(DISTINCT title) 
     FROM table_Y ty
    INNER JOIN table_x tx ON tx.customer_id = ty.customer_id
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ty.title)=1
     GROUP BY marital_status
     ORDER BY tx.customer_id